# Increase price on iOS app subscription

Tags: ios

What happens if you increase you price on an iOS app subscription?
Will subscribers be informed, and how does that procedure look like?
Will the old subscription expire and do they have to confirm and accept the new price?

I have looked through the guidelines but did not find any answers to this.

Thanks

Comment: According to [this article](http://gigaom.com/apple/how-in-app-ios-subscriptions-will-work/), raising the price of a subscription drops the automatic renewal.  The user would have to opt-in again.  Which makes sense; it prevents companies from silently raising the prices without notification.

Comment: As of 8 Dec 2016, iTunes Connect now provides the option to allow existing subscribers to continue at the old price. Search [this page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/) for the text "Keep Subscribers at Their Existing Price". Extra details and demo from the WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016-301/?time=1210